# Does $f(a)=f(b)+f'(b)(a-b)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(a-b)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(a-b)^{n+1}$ on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis

**Taylor-Lagrange** says that if $f$ is $\mathcal C^n([a,b])$ and $n+1$ times derivable, then there is a $c\in]a,b[$ such that $$f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(b-a)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(b-a)^{n+1}.$$
But is it also true that:

if $f$ is $\mathcal C^n([a,b])$ and $n+1$ times derivable, then there is a $c\in]a,b[$ such that $$f(a)=f(b)+f'(b)(a-b)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(b)}{n!}(a-b)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(a-b)^{n+1}$$

(i.e. with $a,b$ switched)

or not ?

Comment: I corrected it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : Let $g(x)=f(-x)$. Then $g\in\mathcal C^{n}([-b,-a])$ and is $n+1$-derivable. Apply the first theorem to $g$ and work backwards:

$$f(a)=g(-a)=g(-b)+\cdots $$

And use that $g^{(k)}(x)=(-1)^kf^{(k)}(-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course ! And you also have $$f(x)=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_{c,x})}{(n+1)!}(x-c)^{n+1}$$
for a certain $\xi_{c,x}$ that depend on $x$ and $c$ for all $x,c\in [a,b]$

To prove it, apply Rolle theorem at $\varphi:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ defined by $$\varphi(x)=f(x)+(c-x)f'(x)+\frac{(c-x)^2}{2}+...+\frac{(c-x)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)+\frac{(c-x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\alpha$$ where $\alpha$ is a real.